# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in elasticsearch 5.5.3

Tags: elasticsearch

C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\bin>.\elasticsearch.exe
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/elasticsearch/bootstrap/Elasticsearch : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

```
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Exception in thread "main"

Comment: which java version you are using?

Comment: i'm using java 1.8

Comment: C:\Users\User>java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: can you also provide the O/P of `javac -version`

Comment: C:\Users\User>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_201

Comment: thank you for your support i have solved in this error

Comment: i am using multiple jdk that is a problem

Answer (score 0):

OP faced this issue as he was using multiple JDK, and one which was used wasn't compatible with ES.

Read more about this error here [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Once, he used the correct JDK, which was compatible with elasticsearch, he was able to resolve the error.